# Firefox vs. Firefox Mobile (Fennec): Are there javascript detectable differences?

Tags: javascript, firefox, detection, fennec

I've tried to find javascript elements that are supported by the mobile but not by the desktop version of Firefox or vice versa. I'm not interested in the user agent's differences. A difference between CSS support maybe helpful, too. Do you know a reliable way to detect differences?

Comment: @hello71 actually he mentioned above that he wasn't interested in ua sniffing. but you were too busy being the kewl brogrammer that you are. what exactly is called user agent? a user agent is software to be utilized by a user. if anyone has no clue what they're doing in web development, as well as in forums, it is you. YOU MEANT TO SAY USE FEATURE DETECTION. now you should say that 100x until you understand it. and you should also apologize to the owner.

Comment: @hello71 I know many discussions about pros and cons of browser sniffing. Sometimes it maybe useful, and sometimes not. Your comment is not helpful. Neither my question is answered nor you give an argument to underline your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

-moz-touch-enabled CSS media query is only on mobile. there are a few more other mobile specific api's as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Firefox_Mobile_for_developers

Comment: Thank you. But this media query is implemented in the desktop version, too. It's only quite useless for desktops. Is there another chance, e.g. a bug, to detect Fennec easier or is a script available to determine viewport's settings/effect?

Comment: did you look at that link? it lists a number of mobile only apis

Comment: Yes, I've read the article but the mentioned APIs list CSS and viewport features only. They do exist in both - the mobile and the desktop - versions.